# How to implement p-autocomplete with checkbox?

Tags: angular6, primeng

I am looking for something p-autocomplete with result having checkboxes for every row and can allow multiple rows from the result.

Please guide me with the best possible solution or an idea with I can proceed.
Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using **multiselect** that have all the feature that you want to implement in auto-complete with a checkbox.

Writing custom functionality in a component that would be riskier than using that already built-in component that has these functionalities. This will help get less error-prone components. Writing custom checkboxes in autocomplete need lots of implementation apart from functional like accessibility, arrow keys actions, etc. So go with **multi-select**.

So for auto-complete in multi-select component use can use the filter property.

[multiselect](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect)